# A function to find out if a String is numerical throws an exception

Tags: java, input

I'm using this function to find out if a String is numerical

```
public static boolean esNumerico(String s) {  
    return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\,?\\d+");   
    }
```

When the program starts, It asks the user to introduce a number.
If I introduce the number 88,99   It crashes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "98,8"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at actividad03.Ejercicio01.pideEntero(Ejercicio01.java:32)
at actividad03.Ejercicio01.main(Ejercicio01.java:14)
```

The complete function code is:

```
  static int pideEntero(){
    int number1;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String str = null;
    try{
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero:");
              str = br.readLine(); //Toma una línea y la almacena como String
        } while (esNumerico(str)==false);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println("Dato no válido.");
    }

    number1=Integer.parseInt(str);
    System.out.println("Valor numérico correcto!");
    //number1=Integer.parseInt(str);
    return number1;
    }
```

The aim is that the user can introduce various kind of imputs. Whenever them are not numeric or integer numeric, the program will ask again to introduce the number, but NOT CRASH as it happens now. Any idea?

Comment: The trace tells you it crashes in parseInt, because it expects an int. Either try-catch the call, or ensure first your number is an int.

Comment: The solution was to implement another function to find out to what extent the Sting is numeric or not. This way: public static boolean esNumero (String s)

  {

  try 

    {

   Integer.parseInt(s);

   return true; 

    }


         catch (NumberFormatException e){return false;}

        }

Comment: `98,8` is *maybe* numeric but it is **not** an integer

Answer (score 2):

It is crash in in the below line as you connot convert comma separated string literal to Integer.

```
number1=Integer.parseInt(str);
```

You may wanna do this instead.

```
 number1 = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be an much simpler way to handle your problem.  You could just try to directly parse the input as a double, and then ensure that no `NumberFormatException` was being thrown.  Something like this:

```
double number1;
do {
    System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero:");
    try {
        str = br.readLine();
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
        // with a valid input in hand, we can now break and leave the loop
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("El numero es inválido, introduzca otra vez:");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Otro problema, introduzca otra vez:");
    }
} while (esNumerico(str) == false);
```

This is probably the way to go actually, because we let Java determine what is and is not a valid string number, rather than trying to guess ourselves using a regex.

If you must continue with your current approach, then keep reading.  Your code has a problem because it is validating for a *double*, not an integer, yet you are attempting to parse the validated input as integer via this:

```
number1 = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Instead, if the number passes validation, use this code to parse as a double:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
Number number = format.parse(str);
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

There is also a problem with your regex used for validation, because a number such as `+98,8` will not parse correctly as a double (though `-99,8` will).  Try using this instead:

```
public static boolean esNumerico(String s) {
    return s.matches("[-]?\\d+(,\\d+)?");
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
[-]?      match an optional leading minus sign
\\d+      followed by one or more digits
(,\\d+)?  followed by an optional comma, and then one or more digits
```

If you want to allow for leading plus sign, then modify the regex, but note that you will have to remove it before parsing the string into a double.

Answer (score 0):

Following line is throwing error

```
number1=Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

A new solution:

```
public static boolean esNumero (String s)

    {

    try 

      {

        Integer.parseInt(s);

        return true;    

      }


     catch (NumberFormatException e){return false;}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt() does not support commas used for separating digits in some countries. Instead DecimalFormat can be used which does allow this.

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
System.out.println(format.parse("12,34").intValue());
```

Output

```
8899
```

Note: DecimalFormat is dependent on Locale, it happens that in my current location then my Local is en_GB which means groupingUsed flag is on by default. You can force it by calling...

```
format.setGroupingUsed(true);
```

NumberFormat instances thow ParseException when inputs are invalid so this can be used to also validate your number

```
try {
    System.out.println(format.parse("88,99").intValue());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // do something else
}
```